# Limit of inverse trigonometric function under composition of functions

Tags: limits

I am not getting why
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 } \arcsin(\sec x)$$

doesn't exist ?  I am confused because $\arcsin$ is continuous in nbd of $0$ and $\sec x \to 1$ as $x\to 0$, so what is the problem in existence?

Comment: there is a limit

Comment: what Kind of Theorems can you use?

Comment: Are you getting my question sir because I am not able to type it using proper mathjax language

Comment: alearner: I provided you with correct formatting, which you deleted, only to write a pretty poorly written,  mere problem statement, with not context.  I won't edit again.

Comment: Sir that was not intentionally but by my mistake. I am keen to learn things but without your kind support how will I learn

Comment: @alearner $\sec x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$ and $\arcsin 1=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ where is the problem?

Comment: The limit does exist, so I don't understand what this question is trying to ask. @Raffaele has given you the correct answer.

Comment: Yes but my teacher said it doesn't exist because as x tends to zero,secx tends to 1 but not exactly1 which means limit doesn't exist as if secx  not exactly 1 then function arcsin (sec x) would have nothing in domain

Comment: Are you getting my point sir?

Comment: Look at my answer @Raffaele

Answer (score 2):

I actually think this is a good question

Assuming this is only in the real number system, $\sec(x)$ as $x$ is near $0$ will be greater than $1$. $\arcsin$ is not defined for anything greater than $1$, therefore, your limit doesn't exist.

The reason you can't plug it in and get $\pi/2$ is because the function is a point at $(0,\pi/2)$, there's nothing around it for the limit to converge to that point from.

Do note that if you're using the complex number system, there is a limit

Comment: I see! $\sec x\geq 1$ Thank you for the message...

Comment: @Raffaele, only around $0$, it's negative at some points

Answer (score 0):

Over the real numbers, $\sec(x)>1$ for all intervals $[-\epsilon, \epsilon] \setminus \{0\}$

So, for any $a_n\to 0$, $\arcsin(\sec(a_n))$ doesn't exist because $\arcsin(y)$ isn't defined for $y>1$